# How to pass date values in an array to a collection?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array in the form:

```
["1/1/2019", "1/2/2019", "1/2/2019"]
```

I loop through each element in the array and add the result to a collection, with the intention of removing duplicates before printing.

VBA adds only the first element to my collection.

E.g. my output is currently:

```
"1/1/2019"
```

Instead of:

```
"1/1/2019","1/2/2019"
```

Here is my relevant code:

```
Dim a_date() As Variant
Dim date_duplicates_removed As New Collection

Dim j As Long
j = 0
ReDim a_date(Range(date_range).Cells.Count)
For Each r In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name").Range(date_range)
    a_date(j) = r.Value
    j = j + 1
Next r
On Error Resume Next
For x = 0 To UBound(a_date)
    date_duplicates_removed.Add a_date(x), CStr(a_date(x))
    MsgBox (date_duplicates_removed(x))
Next x
```

Where date would be a range of dates with duplicates included.

It's strange because:

- I checked UBound(date) and the result was 12
- I accessed MsgBox date_duplicates_removed(3) and got a value.
- x does increment to the correct result.

I cannot get the MsgBox to print all the unique dates and only the first one.

Comment: Are you able to do `Dim date() as Variant`? `Date()` is a reserved word in VBA as far as I know...Also, are you missing some code, where do you input your array?

Comment: Sorry, I changed my actual variable name to simplify the code. I didn't actually use "date". I also updated my question to include code where I input the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's how you're using the array, and/or `Date()`:

```
Sub t()
Dim myDates() As Variant
Dim date_duplicates_removed As New Collection
myDates = Array("1/1/2019", "1/2/2019", "1/2/2019")
Dim x As Long

On Error Resume Next
For x = 0 To UBound(myDates)
    date_duplicates_removed.Add myDates(x), CStr(myDates(x))
Next x
End Sub
```

Returns correctly for me: 
[image]

Comment: I assume it's some bizarre glitch with VBA.

IF I do date_duplicates_removed.count I get 4 so it must have all the entries de-duplicated.

Thank you,